# $(this) vs this in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between `$(this)` and `this` in jQuery ? Here are two different usage :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#orderedlist").find("li").each(function(i) {
     $(this).append( " BAM! " + i );
   });
 });


 $(document).ready(function() {
   // use this to reset several forms at once
   $("#reset").click(function() {
     $("form").each(function() {
       this.reset();
     });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "this" variable refers (in such cases as the event handlers you've supplied) to a DOM element. Thus $(this) is a jQuery object containing just that one DOM element.

You should use plain "this" when the native DOM APIs suffice, and $(this) when you need the help of jQuery. Your second example is a good illustration; another might be when you just need the "id" or "name" of an element.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that `this` by itself is a reference to the dom object that the event is acting upon. `$(this)` is creating a jquery object from that dom object.

EDIT: So with the DOM object you aren't going to have access to all the jquery added functionality but only what the dom allows. Basically you can think of the `this` by itself as the same as if you did `document.getElementById(id)`

Comment: "`this` _by itself is a reference to the dom object that the event is acting upon_", so far the most beautiful definition for getting to know `this`, Thumbs up buddy : ) !

Answer (score 8):

`$(this)` is a jquery object while `this` refers to native dom object