# Jquery val() vs this.value for dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

The below code uses this.value to get the value of a forms dropdowns. I have only generally seen .val() used. Is the below way acceptable cross-browser (especially older verions of IE)? Thanks!

```
    $(':input', '#all').each(function() {
       alert(this.value);                 
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's acceptable, is more readable, and is less expensive (faster) than calling `$(this).val()`.

Simply put, `$(this)` refers to a jQuery object, whilst `this` refers to a DOM element.

The FAQ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) touches upon it briefly (under 'Know Your DOM Properties and Functions')

> You should use plain "this" when the native DOM APIs suffice, and
>   $(this) when you need the help of jQuery.

I'd also suggest reading the following:

[$(this) vs this in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400020/this-vs-this-in-jquery)

[jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

[When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery/4652402#4652402)

[utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element)

[this demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)

Comment: you need alot of input fields until you wil notice the difference in performance

Answer (score -1):

This should work

For JQuery `val` you need `$(this).val()`