# Disable or enable only the current button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

With a PHP for each cycle, I'm bringing articles from the database. In those articles, we have a comment section with a form. I want to check with jQuery if there is something written on the input before the comment is sent.

As the articles are being brought with a PHP cycle, I want to check only the article in which it is being written a comment, but jQuery checks all the articles and only enables or disables the first or top result being brought from the database. I want jQuery to check only on the article with a written comment.

Here's what I'm doing:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".comment-submit").attr("disabled", true);

  $("#group-post-comment-input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
      $(".comment-submit").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $(".comment-submit").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" id="group-post-comment-input">

  <button class="comment-submit">
        Comment
    </button>
</form>

<br>

<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" id="group-post-comment-input">

  <button class="comment-submit">
        Comment
    </button>
</form>

<br>

<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" id="group-post-comment-input">

  <button class="comment-submit">
        Comment
    </button>
</form>
```

As you can see on the snippet above, the buttons only get enabled when text is written on the first input only. I want the buttons to get enabled when text is written on their dependent input. If input 2 has text on it, enable button 2, and so on and so on.

How can I do that?

Comment: only with the older jQuery ? not in JavaScript code (ES10) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176582/enable-disable-a-button-in-pure-javascript/41176769#41176769

Comment: your HTML code is wrong because `id` attributes must be with an unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [IDs must be unique to the DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page), you might consider using a class instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".group-post-comment-input").on('keyup', function() {
    let $button = $(this).next('.comment-submit');
    let disabled = !this.value;
    $button.prop('disabled', disabled);
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" class="group-post-comment-input">
  <button class="comment-submit" disabled>Comment</button>
</form>

<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" class="group-post-comment-input">
  <button class="comment-submit" disabled>Comment</button>
</form>

<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" class="group-post-comment-input">
  <button class="comment-submit" disabled>Comment</button>
</form>
```

In my demonstration, I use jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to traverse from the `input` on which the "keyup" event is fired to its associated `button`.

> *.next( [selector ] )*
> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Another method is to traverse up to the form element with [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and back down to the button with [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/). This might be useful if you expect your HTML structure to change in a way that could break the `next()` traversal.

```
let $button = $(this).closest('form').find('.comment-submit');
```

I also recommend using [`prop()` instead of `attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) to enable and disable inputs.

Comment: This solution is great. With !this.value, what do you mean? It is being used to change the disabled/enabled attribute, but can it be used to change other things such as the background color? If so, how?

Comment: Empty input values are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). The [logical not (!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#using_not) returns `true` when the value is an empty string and `false` when it is not. Using [`.prop(propertyName,value)`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2), an input is `disabled` when its value is empty. The boolean value could also be used to toggle a class that applies a background color. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also, I'm using `this.value` to access the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) attribute of the input element. You could use jQuery: `$(this).val()`. See [Jquery val() vs this.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834252/jquery-val-vs-this-value-for-dropdowns) and [jQuery(#id).val() vs. getElementById(#id).value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322078/jqueryid-val-vs-getelementbyidid-value).

Comment: If they can be used to toggle classes, how? I'm new to jQuery

Comment: One method is jQuery's [`toggleClass(classNames,state)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state), which accepts a Boolean `state` parameter that determines "whether the class should be added or removed".

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique,
but you need to use a **name** for sending information to your PHP server

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.comment-submit').forEach( bt => bt.disabled = true )

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="group-post-comment-input"]').forEach( inEl => 
   inEl.oninput = e =>inEl.nextElementSibling.disabled = (inEl.value.trim().length === 0) )
```

```html
<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" name="group-post-comment-input">
  <button class="comment-submit"> Comment </button>
</form>
<br>
<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" name="group-post-comment-input">
  <button class="comment-submit"> Comment </button>
</form>
<br>
<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" name="group-post-comment-input">
  <button class="comment-submit"> Comment </button>
</form>
```